# No row returned from db - but there are records to be returned

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

I am executing the select statement with using jdbc sybase driver (`jconn3`). I checked the statement with executed manually on isql and all rows returned correctly. The statement which is executing on jdbc :

```
select * from mytable where date between ? and ?
```

I added the dateformat as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and set the time value as 00:00:00 for begin date and  23:59:59 for end date.

It is not working. The row count must be 1000 but it is sometimes 770, sometimes 990, sometimes 564 etc.. There is no any specific row count which everytime returned.

After that I added an extra execution which returns only row count.  First I am executing the  `select count(*) from ...`  statement then executing `select * from ....`  and now `select * from ... query returns the correct number of records everytime. This can not be related with caching. And weird thing is , I am using same preparedstatement and resultset objects for those two execution.

Any idea on that issue?

@Rulmeq, here is the code (added on 2012-03-29)

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

ps = myConn.getConnection().prepareStatement("select count(*) from myTable where date between ? and ?");
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(beginDate.getTime()));   // format : yyyy-MM-dd
ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime()));    // format : yyyy-MM-dd
rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
// some logs here

ps = myConn.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from myTable where date between ? and ?");
ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(beginDate.getTime()));    // format : yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss  
ps.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(endDate.getTime()));  // format : yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss  
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    ........
}
```

Comment: @Rulmeq, I added the code in question.

Comment: Can you include your instantiation (definition) of beginDate and endDate in your code. They seem to be the key here.

Comment: @Aykut:`set the time value as 00:00:00 for begin date and 23:59:59 for end date.' Why you are not taking same time format for initialization? Is that for specific purpose? Because of that 1 day is counted more.

Comment: Thanks @SomnathMuluk. I did not write it here but I already did it.I don't have time to write the whole functions here now but will write it asap.

Comment: using a `java.sql.Date` will "reset" the time to 00:00 so I would expect the first part of your code (using `java.sql.Date`) will not return rows where the time of the "last" day is > 00:00. But I'm surprised that the version with a timestamp does not work properly. Are you sure you are initializing the time part correctly? What happens if you use literals instead of parameters?

Comment: Some items to note:
1) The initialization of beginDate and EndDate is missing for your code.  The reason this is important is because it is possible that may be the source of the error.  
2) In the example you are calling the prepared statement with java.sql.Date and java.sql.Timestamp.  What is the target JDBC data type? DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP?
3) When you dump the output of the preparedStatement (once it has been "set" using ps.toString() ) and you execute it directly on the database, do you get different result sets?

Comment: I don't like the driver provided by Sybase since I had my issues with it. Have you tried using jTDS?

Comment: @Uberslodat, No i did not. will try

Comment: You might also want to check what version of the JDBC drvier you are using, older version have been known to have weird 'issues'

Comment: @J.Henderson, 1. begindate and endDate initialization is works fine. No problem on that. I did not write it here. 2. datatype is timestamp. When we use setDate, jdbc does not set any time value to parameter. and if I insert a value to date column , time part becomes "12:00:00 am" by default. I just test it. 3. I got the same resultset when I execute the query from jdbc or directly from db. I found the issue and this issue is not related with jdbc. :/ This is about synchronization of data insertion. I missed the log lines which are related with duplicate references. bye bye +50 :)

Comment: @dann.dev, Thanks. I use jconn3 as I wrote in question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all  but issue has been solved and it was not related with jdbc. It was related with using System.currentTimeMillis() and host system is too fast. That's why system sometime uses the same ms. I changed the references.

Answer (score 2):

What I think the problem is the code you are using to assign datetime values to the query arguments. And now as you specified that  the code with "select * from ..." is working fine, so i think the only difference between them is that you can use

```
ps = myConn.getConnection().prepareStatement("select Count(*) from myTable where date between ? and ?");
ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(beginDate.getTime()));
ps.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(endDate.getTime()));  
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

for "select Count(*) from .."

Comment: @Shanbaz, this is not a solution but you analyzed well. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Is date defined as date, datetime, smalldatetime or timestamp in myTable?  You are using setDate and setTimestamp.  One of them doesn't match the date type defined in myTable.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle TO_DATE function would help like below.

```
 "select count(*) from myTable where date between TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd') and TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')"
```

Comment: Thx but we are using sybase ase